# What can I use to help me conjugate verbs?

Tags: глаголы, resources

I used to use http://cooljugator.com/ to quickly look up proper ways to conjugate Russian verbs.

The site's been having some problems lately and wasn't accessible. What other resources can I use instead?

Comment: I must be missing something but what does this have to do with this site?

Comment: I voted to close as Not Constructive. Your question is a list question which are not a good fit for the site.

Comment: The site's working again, by the way.

Comment: Thought this site was about learning Russian... conjugating verbs is quite essential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try The *Russian Morphological Dictionary* by Zalizniak, e.g. [here](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/main.cgi?flags=eygtmnl).

There are two more cool and useful dictionaries there.